# TileService getting killed on every 5 seconds in Android 9

Tags: android, service

I've a [`TileService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService.html) which simply toggles it's state to `ACTIVE` and `INACTIVE` on every click on it. Nothing complicated.

I tested the service in `Android 7`, and it works perfectly fine. But in `Android 9`, the `TileService` getting destroyed and recreated on every 5 seconds. I tried setting the service as `ForegroundService` by calling `startForeground`, but it didn't work.

So these are my questions.

1. Why the `TileService` getting killed on every 5 seconds in `Android 9` ?
2. What should I do to run the service without being killed ?

I've checked the official docs of `TileService`, I couldn't see any throttling information defined.

What am I missing ?